# How can I get complete stacktraces for exceptions thrown in tests when using sbt and testng?

Tags: scala, testng, sbt, scalatest, slf4j

The stacktraces are truncated - e.g. they end with `[info]   ...`

Using `last` or changing `traceLevel` doesn't help - it simply prints the complete stacktrace of the sbt wrapper.

This is testing with testng (also I believe using scalatest and sl4j)

Answer (score 74):

Using hints found in the [documentation here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt):

(quoted)

> You can configure the output shown when running with sbt in four ways: 1) turn off color, 2) show short stack traces, 3) full stack traces, and 4) show durations for everything. To do so you must pass a -o argument to ScalaTest, and after the -o, place any combination of:
>
> - D - show durations
> - S - show short stack traces
> - F - show full stack traces
> - W - without color
>
> For example, "-oDF" would show full stack traces and durations (the amount of time spent in each test).
>
> To pass arguments from sbt to ScalaTest you can either add test options globally, like this:
>
> ```
> testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oD")
> ```

(See the website for the rest of the quote)

You can use the following sbt command to enable full stack traces in tests:

```
> set testOptions in YourProjectName += Tests.Argument("-oF")
```

---

Per Sasha's comment, this can also be done from the command line per test run as shown below.

```
sbt test -- -oF
```

Comment: alternatively full stack traces can be enabled during command line test execution with `-- -oF` param: `sbt test -- -oF`

Comment: The problem with the `-oF` flag is that it also shows the full stack traces for something as simple as an incorrect match. There does not need to be a full stack trace for 2 not equals 3. Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: To clarify. If you work interactively and if you're already in the right module, this is sufficient: `set testOptions += Tests.Argument("-oF")`  All next runs within the interactive session will be "stacktrace-ed".

Comment: That `$ sbt test -- -oF` doesn't work, btw. 
sbt.version=1.4.3

Comment: For me ```$ testOnly * -- -oF``` worked.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to getting SBT to print the full stack trace, could you put a `try`-`catch` block around your test runner? For example, from the REPL:

```
scala> try { throw new Exception } catch { case e => e }
res1: java.lang.Throwable = java.lang.Exception

scala> res1.printStackTrace
java.lang.Exception
    at $line2.$read$$iw$$iw$.liftedTree1$1(<console>:8)
    at $line2.$read$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<console>:8)
    at $line2.$read$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<console>)
    ...
```

Comment: `try { throw new Exception } catch { case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace }`