# How to debug tests ran from sbt

Tags: sbt, jpda

Tests run from sbt [don't show an stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237824/how-can-i-get-complete-stacktraces-for-exceptions-thrown-in-tests-when-using-sbt) when an exception happens, so I would like to connect to sbt from a debugger to debug the tests. What is an easy way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the sbt deb/rpm provided by typesafe, this works:

```
sbt -jvm-debug 8000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate sbt launcher with the java jdwp args, i.e.
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,server=y,address=10000

From here, you can connect your debugger to port 10,000.